# Scope of Action parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, scope, action

I've been developing a WPF application, and I've stumbled upon something interesting, probably because I don't know how it really works underneath.

Basically I'm creating a context menu. The menu has one parent MenuItem, which has three children of the same type. Here's the bare bones code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ContextMenu ctxMain = new ContextMenu();

    MenuItem parent = CreateMenuItem("Parent", null);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        parent.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(i.ToString(), () => MessageBox.Show(i.ToString())));
    }

    ctxMain.Items.Add(parent);
    this.ContextMenu = ctxMain;
}


public MenuItem CreateMenuItem(string header, Action action)
{
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    if (action != null)
    {
        item.Click += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => action();
    }
    item.Header = header;
    return item;
}
```

Visually, it's working as expected.

[image]

But the action I've given as parameter is acting strange. I'd expect each child item's click to show what's written in their header in the MessageBox. But all of them are displaying '3'.

Am I understanding it correctly, that the inline action I've defined in the for loop, does not get instantiated three times, but only once, using the same parameter 'i'? Or are they three different Action instances, all referring to the same integer? I'd like to hear some clarification to what's going on here.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var localCopy = i;
    parent.Items.Add(CreateMenuItem(localCopy.ToString(), () => MessageBox.Show(localCopy.ToString())));
}
```

Your variable i was "captured" by the lambda expression. But `i` has changed before your action was executed. And your action executes on the current `i`, which means 3 (the value i has after the loop and when your action finally executes).

You need to make a local copy of your variable and use that instead. As it has it's own scope inside the loop, it will never change.

Comment: I've learned something today. Thanks for the fast and on-spot answer.

Comment: nice example of taking local copy for iterator in loop when using lambda expressions